# How do I find the index of the first occurrence of a score in a sorted Redis set?

Tags: database, parsing, redis

I'm writing a search engine using Dewey Decimal call numbers to categorize information. The scheme is as follows:

123.45

2 is a sub-category of 1.
3 is a sub-category of 2.
4 a sub-category of 3. Etc.

It's the same numbering system libraries use to sort their books. 200 for example is religion. 210 is Philosophy & Theory of Religion. 211 is Concepts of God.

The site is one continuous catalog that goes from one subject to the next. Each link is given a score in Redis (the link's Dewey Decimal call no.). The site is setup for 50 links per page. I've got a function which calculates the zrange to pull from the server depending on the page the user's accessing.

Is there a way that I can specify a score and find the index of the first occurrence matching said score -- that way I don't have to iterate the entire database looking for scores when users enter a call no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ZCOUNT` from negative infinity to your specific score to find the index.

For example, in following sorted set:

```
> ZADD dewey 1 first 3 second 8 third 21 fourth 55 fifth
(integer) 5
```

To find the index of `21` (the fourth number):

```
> ZCOUNT dewey -inf (21
3
```

Just keep in mind that this is 0-based index.